# Queue::push error - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue, laravel-queue

I have this code in my `web.php` in my laravel project :

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
    Queue::push(function(){
        Log::info('12');
        return 'done';
    });
});
```

But when i send request to `http://localhost:8000/` **i have a error** :

```
Closure object cannot have properties
```

I tried like this but i have same error :

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
    Queue::push(function($job){
        Log::info('12');
        return 'done';
        $job->delete();
    });
});
```

> Laravel verrsion is : *5.6*

Comment: I'm pretty sure using a closure here is not supported anymore. Do you have some links to documentation where it's used this way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in you code anyway be sure that is not the problem :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
Queue::push(function($job){
    Log::info('12');
    return 'done';
    $job->delete();
});
 });
```

Replace `$hob` with `$job` .

Comment: i have same error.the mistake in not from hob or job! i used in other ways but i have same error

Comment: ok you should not put properties in function but pass it as a second parameter

Comment: i didn't pas param!

Comment: you have to pass you parms as second parameter like Queue::push(function(){},$job);

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not allowed to pass closure inside `Queue::push`.

You need to pass the Job class like so:

```
Queue::push(MyNewJob::class, $data);
```

And `MyNewJob` should be like this:

```
class MyNewJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function handle()
    {
       Log::info('12');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? It's so weird because there is no closure in my code!

Comment: Let me try again

Comment: I know you're from Iran. If you want you can contact me on my telegram [@holykamix](https://telegram.me/holykamix)